# ClickHouse 500 Response

Tags: python, docker, parquet, clickhouse

I am attempting to insert data into a Docker container in Clickhouse.

I get the following error message some times.

```
DatabaseError: :HTTPDriver for http://localhost:8123 returned response code 500)
 std::exception. Code: 1001, type: std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error, e.what() = filesystem error: in rename: Permission denied [/var/lib/clickhouse/store/027/0275853b-1c75-468f-8275-853b1c75868f/tmp_insert_all_12_12_0/] [/var/lib
```

I can't find any resources online. Has anyone seen this before?

Some of the uploads are successful and sometimes this code is returned.

Comment: Please see the Volumes section in the Docker Hub guide here:  https://hub.docker.com/r/clickhouse/clickhouse-server/

Comment: In particular to persist data you will probably want to mount a volume with a path of `/var/lib/clickhouse` for your data and `/var/log/clickhouse-server` for your logs